# How do I implement a jQuery delay on hiding search bar after mouseover? (Shopify)

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I am using Shopify for a retail store and the search bar is very touchy when hovering over the search icon. As you can see in the gif, the search bar disappears very quickly when moving the mouse down from the search icon to the search bar.

search bar gif - http://recordit.co/YvsZYDLaH8

How do I get the search bar to keep from disappearing so quickly when mousing down to the search bar?  Below is the jQuery I found for the search-form :hover effect.

```
  jQuery('#search-top').hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.search-form').stop().delay(2).show()();
  },
  function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('active').find('.search-form').stop().delay(2).hide();
  }
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you tried fadeIn() and fadeOut() ?

Comment: you tried to increase the Delay value? 2 milliseconds is quite short

Comment: I used the fadeIn() and fadeOut() but that gives me the same issue with the search bar, just with a fade effect. gif - http://recordit.co/kySVtPLAji

Comment: @KyleMoser so non of the provided answers helped you?

Comment: @hansTheFranz Not quite yet, I do like the idea of having it as a user click option instead of hover that J Smith suggested below. I implemented the code he suggested but I ran into a small issue.. the search bar appears when I click on the search icon, but the search bar disappears when i click on the search bar to type something.
 (gif - recordit.co/BtFvd4o98C) seems like it should be an easy fix but I'm stumped. here's the code i used. What do I need to add?

  $('#search-top').click(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').find('.search-form').toggle();
    }
  );

Answer (score 0):

The delay of 2 milliseconds is a too short, you can increase it to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds). Try several values to see which one you like better:

```
jQuery('#search-top').hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.search-form').stop().delay(800).show();
  },
  function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('active').find('.search-form').stop().delay(2000).hide();
  }
);
```

Both suggestions in the comments are good, so instead of the delay, you can use the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions to add a bit of animation to the showing and hiding of the search box.

Note: you have an extra pair of parentheses after your `show()`. I removed them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking for a user *click*, not a user hover. I would recommend using this model:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function () {
    $('#toggled').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click to Toggle</button>
  <p id="toggled">Am I displayed?</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This method will toggle whether or not the paragraph appears. You might want to make your code toggle on a user click, as it gives the user more control over what happens.

Comment: I do like the idea of maybe having it as a user click option.  Where did I go wrong here?  The search bar appears when I click on the search icon, but the search bar disappears when i click on the search form(gif - http://recordit.co/BtFvd4o98C).. seems like it should be an easy fix though. here's the code i used.

  jQuery('#search-top').click(
      function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.search-form').toggle();
      },
      function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active').find('.search-form').toggle();
      }
    );

Comment: Without seeing your HTML code, I can't know for sure what is wrong. My best guess is, however, that the search box is a child of the #search-top. This is a problem, any click on the search box would also click the #search-top. Be sure that your html looks like so:

<html>
<body>
<div id="search-top"></div>
<!-- The search top and search form are seperate so clicking the search form doesn't trigger the jquery and hide it -->
<div class="search-form"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I will mess around with this some more.  The html for the search form is as follows: <div id="search-top">
                <div class="icon-search"><i class="icon_search"> </i></div>
                <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
                  <div class="search-close">
                      <i class="icon_close"></i>
                  </div>
                  {% include 'search-bar' %}
                </div>
              </div>

Comment: I looked at your code, here it a weave that works properly.
http://liveweave.com/bokcXz
I left everything close to as it was, but I did make minor changes to make it nicer (and work, of course). Plus, I wouldn't mind if you gave me the best answer, as I am trying to build my reputation.